# Appbar title text fontSize not changing

Tags: flutter, dart

Desired outcome: change the font size of the text in the title of `AppBar`

What I've tried: update fontSize in titleTextStyle in AppBarTheme

```
MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            elevation: 0.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 40,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        home: MainScreen(),
      ),
```

Still, the font size remains unchanged.

Why?

Comment: I tried your code and it works well in my system. please share `MainScreen`. do you use any other `textStyle` in appBar?

Comment: @Abbasihsn is it possibly because i'm running my code on web emulator?

Comment: yes, it can. Actually, I think you should use `.copyWith` in that case for the headline. see this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63918